# Grid background image height gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

im trying to build a responsive image gallery of three columns and two rows with max width of 800px. And i would like to get ride of the gap its create when i define the height of the background images.

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
    
}
.grid {
    max-width: 800px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2px;
    width: 100%;
}
.img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-image:url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="trash.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="grid">
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
            <div class="img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

then don't set the height to `300px`

Set it to auto

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work, it won't show the image

Comment: y don't you load the images inside the html?
@CristianMarcos

But on the css

Comment: i tried what you just said and it did work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you use `bckground-size: contain` it will keep the image ratio and won't work with height.

if you add `background-size: cover` it will work fine on that.

try this

```
.img {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the image will always have the same ratio use the padding trick

```css
.grid {
  max-width: 800px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.img {
  padding-top: 56%;
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/1600x900');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```